# Cannot ping/ssh devices connected to a DD-WRT router

Tags: networking, router, ping, dd-wrt

I have tried to find similar questions / google it but it seems pretty hard to find a case that exactly matches mine.

I have a TP-Link wdr3500 router with DD-WRT flashed on it. The router gateway is `192.168.1.1` I have tested it with the following devices:

- Device **A**: My desktop, running Win 10 - *wired* `192.168.1.131`
- Device **B**: My Intel NUC, running Ubuntu Server 16.04 - *wired* `192.168.1.111`
- Device **C**: MacBook Pro - *wireless 5.0* `192.168.1.113`
- Device **D**: Chromecast - *wireless 5.0* `192.168.1.112`
- Device **E**: Thinkpad laptop - *wireless 2.4* `192.168.1.117`

These are the connections I tested:

- From **A**, I can only ping **C** and **D**
- From **B**, I can only ping **C** and **D** (**A** gives me `From 192.168.1.111 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable`, while **E** just times out)
- From **C** and **D** I can ping everything except **E**
- From **E** I can ping everything.

I would like to be able to ping everything from anything, does anyone have a clue what is wrong with my setup, and where and how can I fix it ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: E may be configured not to answer pings. B may have the netmask `/25` (or even more restrictive), which makes `192.168.1.131` out of its subnet. A, C and D may be OK. Just guessing.

Comment: Connecting from A to B is the most important for me. If I run `ip addr` on B, I get the IP `192.168.1.111/24` so it should be in the same subnet right ?

Comment: Right. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22110622). I would examine `arp` on B. At the moment I can't help you more.

Comment: `arp` on B is saying `(incomplete)` for `192.168.1.131` (A). While that post  kindof explain what that means, it didn't help me figure out my next step. Thanks for the help, hopefully someone else can pitch in?

Comment: Add a static entry on B for testing: `sudo arp -s 192.168.1.131 MA:C_:of:A_:he:re`.

Comment: I just tried it out, the `ping` just basically hangs until I abort it.